# Apply, sapply, mapply, lapply, vapply,rapply, tapply, replicate, aggregate, by e correlatos no R. Quando e como utilizar?

Tags: r, apply, sapply, lapply, mapply

Qual a diferença entre as funções `apply`, `sapply`, `mapply`, `lapply`, `vapply`, `rapply`, `tapply`, `replicate`, `aggregate`, `by` e correlatas no R?

Quando e como utilizar cada uma delas?

Há outros pacotes que fazem algo similar ou podem substituir essas funções?

Comment: Veja se esse post pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/3096200 Abraço, Luiz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Traduzindo [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

R possui muitas funções *apply que estão bem explicadas no help (e.g. `?apply`). Como existem muitas, alguns usuaRios novátos podem ter dificuldades em decidir qual é apropriada pra sua situação ou até mesmo lembrar de todas.

- **apply** - *Quando você quer aplicar a função às linhas ou colunas de uma matriz.*

  ```
  # Matriz de duas dimensões
  M <- matrix(seq(1,16), 4, 4)

  # apply min às linhas
  apply(M, 1, min)
  [1] 1 2 3 4

  # apply min às colunas
  apply(M, 2, max)
  [1]  4  8 12 16

  # Array tridimensional
  M <- array( seq(32), dim = c(4,4,2))

  #  Aplicar soma em cada M [ * ], - isto é, através de Soma 2 ª e 3 ª dimensão
  apply(M, 1, sum)
  # O resultado é unidimensional
  [1] 120 128 136 144

  # Aplicar soma em cada M [ * , * ] - ou seja, através de Soma 3 ª dimensão
  apply(M, c(1,2), sum)
  # O resultado é bidimensional 
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]   18   26   34   42
  [2,]   20   28   36   44
  [3,]   22   30   38   46
  [4,]   24   32   40   48
  ```
- **lapply** - *Quando você quer aplicar uma função para cada elemento de uma lista e receber uma lista de volta.*

  Este é o carro-chefe de muitas das outras funções *apply.

  ```
     x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100) 
     lapply(x, FUN = length) 
     $a 
     [1] 1
     $b 
     [1] 3
     $c 
     [1] 91

     lapply(x, FUN = sum) 
     $a 
     [1] 1
     $b 
     [1] 6
     $c 
     [1] 5005
  ```
- **sapply** - *Quando você quer aplicar a funcão para cada elemento de uma lista, porém quer retornar um **vetor** ao invés de uma lista.*

  Ao invés de utilizar `unlist(lapply(...))`, considere o uso de 
  `sapply`.

  ```
     x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100)
     #Compare com acima; um vetor chamado , não uma lista
     sapply(x, FUN = length)  
     a  b  c   
     1  3 91

     sapply(x, FUN = sum)   
     a    b    c    
     1    6 5005
  ```

  Em usos mais avançados do `sapply` a função tentará resultar em uma matriz multi- dimensional , se apropriado. Por exemplo, se nossa função retorna vetores do mesmo comprimento , `sapply` vai usá-las como colunas de uma matriz:

  ```
     sapply(1:5,function(x) rnorm(3,x))
  ```

  Se nossa função retorna uma matriz de 2 dimensões, `sapply` vai fazer essencialmente a mesma coisa, tratando cada matriz como um único vetor:

  ```
     sapply(1:5,function(x) matrix(x,2,2))
  ```

  A menos que especifiquemos `simplify = "array"`, caso em que ele vai usar as matrizes individuais para construir um array multi- dimensional:

  ```
     sapply(1:5,function(x) matrix(x,2,2), simplify = "array")
  ```
- **vapply** - *Para quando você quer utilizar o `sapply` mas talvez precise de um código mais rápido.*

  Por `vapply`, você basicamente dá ao R um exemplo de que tipo de função irá retornar, o que pode aumentar sua performance.

  ```
  x <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, c = 10:100)
  # Note que uma vez que o avanço aqui é principalmente a velocidade , este
  # Exemplo é apenas para ilustração. Estamos dizendo que R
  # Tudo voltou por length () deve ser um número inteiro de
  # Comprimento 1. 
  vapply(x, FUN = length, FUN.VALUE = 0) 
  a  b  c  
  1  3 91
  ```
- **mapply** - *Para quando você tem várias estruturas de dados diferentes(e.g.
  vetores, listas) e você quer aplicar a função para os primeiros elementos de cada e então os segundos, etc., forçando o resultado em um vetor ou array como em `sapply`.*

  Nesse caso sua função deve aceitar múltiplos argumentos.

  ```
  #Soma os 1ºs elementos, os 2ºs elementos, etc. 
  mapply(sum, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5) 
  [1]  3  6  9 12 15
  #Para fazer rep(1,4), rep(2,3), etc.
  mapply(rep, 1:4, 4:1)   
  [[1]]
  [1] 1 1 1 1

  [[2]]
  [1] 2 2 2

  [[3]]
  [1] 3 3

  [[4]]
  [1] 4
  ```
- **rapply** - *Para quando você quer aplicar a função para cada elemento de uma **lista aninhada** de forma recursiva.*

  ```
  #Adiciona ! na string, ou incrementa
  myFun <- function(x){
      if (is.character(x)){
      return(paste(x,"!",sep=""))
      }
      else{
      return(x + 1)
      }
  }

  #Estrutura da lista
  l <- list(a = list(a1 = "Boo", b1 = 2, c1 = "Eeek"), 
            b = 3, c = "Yikes", 
            d = list(a2 = 1, b2 = list(a3 = "Hey", b3 = 5)))


  #O resultado é um vetor ligado ao caractere         
  rapply(l,myFun)

  #O resultado é uma lista como l, porém com os valores alterados
  rapply(l, myFun, how = "replace")
  ```
- **tapply** - *Para quando você quiser aplicar a função à  **subsetores** de um vetor e estes são definidos por outro vetor.*

  Um vetor:

  ```
     x <- 1:20
  ```

  A fator (do mesmo tamanho!) definindo os grupos:

  ```
     y <- factor(rep(letters[1:5], each = 4))
  ```

  Adicione os valores em `x` em cada subgrupo definido por `y`:

  ```
     tapply(x, y, sum)  
      a  b  c  d  e  
     10 26 42 58 74
  ```

  - **Aggregate e by** - É relativamente fácil de recolher dados em `R` utilizando um ou mais `BY` variáveis ​​e uma função definida.

> attach(mtcars)
>   aggdata <-aggregate(mtcars, by=list(cyl,vs),
>     FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
>   print(aggdata)
>   detach(mtcars)

Comment: Filipe, vou dar preferência a uma resposta original (caso seja tão boa e completa, claro), mas se não aparecer você recebe!

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns Filipe!!

Answer (score 3):

Acho que a melhor maneira de descobrir qualquer coisa em R é aprender pela experimentação, usando dados e funções embaraçosamente triviais.

Se você ligar o seu console de R, digite "apply" e desça até as funções no pacote base, você verá algo como isto:

```
1: base::apply             aplicar aplicar funções sobre Margens de matriz 
2: base::by                aplicar uma função de um quadro de dados Dividido por Fatores
3: base::eapply            aplique uma função acima de valores em um ambiente
4: base::lapply            aplicar uma função sobre uma lista ou vetor
5: base::mapply            aplicar uma função para listar vários ou Argumentos vetoriais
6: base::rapply            aplicar recursively uma função a uma lista 
7: base::tapply            aplicar uma função sobre uma matriz Ragged
```

exemplo usando o eapply:

```
    # a new environment
    e <- new.env()
    # two environment variables, a and b
    e$a <- 1:10
    e$b <- 11:20
    # mean of the variables
    eapply(e, mean)
    $b
    [1] 15.5
    $a
    [1] 5.5
```

[Fonte](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/)